# How to find whether a game is valid or not?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to find out if the game that the user is playing is an actual game recognized by Discord.

I am able to get the game through `user.presence.game`, but if users change their "PLAYING" activity to something random it still shows up as a game.

Is `game.applicationID` unique to a game and can it be used to determine it's validity, or is there another method?

Answer (score 0):

`<Game>.applicationID`'s are bound to the games that are published on Discord's store and applications that bind their application ID to the SDK. It would be possible to determine if it is a game with that, but take into account that large percentage of the games doesn't even use Discord's SDK nor they're published through Discord.

Answer (score 0):

As deyyanl said, the Discord SDK isn't a very good way to evaluate whether a user plays a game.

Although it's not a very solid answer, have you thought about checking the game's name (in the user's status) in a video games database? 1 Google search led me [there](https://api-docs.igdb.com/).